# Generic Collections to be used as a parameter of invoke command

Tags: c#, generics, collections

Edited : got it worked.
Generic Collections to be used as a parameter of invoke command

--
Removed the brackets from ... SetListDelegate(SetList) in the invoke command of mine

Comment: Please do keep your question. If you remove the original question no one else can find it and learn from it.

Comment: Ok, Ill post it back, I messed it up with some other questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name your method parameter. And you are missing the generic argument.

Something like this will do

```
public delegate void SetListDelegate<T>(List<T> l );

public void SetList<T> (List<T> l)
{
    if ( lstW.InvokeRequired)
        lstW.Invoke(new SetListDelegate<T>(SetList<T>), l);
    else
        lstW.Items.AddRange(l);
}
```

**Edit:**
If this is contained in a class with the generic argument `<T>` you don't need it on the delegate or the method.